# Div in Position Fixed with background image under a div in position absolute with content

Tags: css, html, background-image, css-position

I want to change the way i am displaying the background image in my pages to gain more flexibility.

Here my CSS Code at the moment in the `section id="home"` where the image is displayed:

```
background-image: url("/img/architecture.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center 1115px;
height: 350px;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 35px;
box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0 #888888 inset;
```

I want to do the same thing but in this way: Create a div in position fixed with this Background-image in the same position and then put above the web page content in an other div (in position absolute?). IS that possible? How can you achieve that? Hope the explanation is clear

Here my page: http://tommywebdesigner.com/Home%20Page.html
And also : http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/

Comment: could you explain a little better, it might just be but im not getting what you wanna achive here....

Comment: Do you mean so that the menu and the large image scroll with the page? if so, you need to set the #home to position:fixed; and also change the header to position:fixed; and style it a bit more so it looks like it does now

Comment: Ok, in other words, i want to achieve the same effect as now but in a different way using div. I want a div in position fixed with the image as background in the same position, and above an other div with my page content. So in this way if i scroll the div with the content the div with the background-image keep fixed. IS it bit clearer now? Thanks  P.s Image when you look up outside in a window, the same effect! :)

Comment: first define  div class for the whole page and apply background color which ever u want. Then divide that defined div class as per your needs. Suppose you want header 50px height so define a div class of height 50px. Then another div class of 300px for background imag. Then div class for content.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a different way? If it works as it is, what would be the added value of changing it?

Comment: You are totally right Gareth, the thing is that probably my client wants to put also a video where there is the Background-image now, so i thought this might be the solution when the client is gonna ask me to put the video there instead of the image background. :(

Comment: Ah, I see. I think it is probably possible if you use `z-index` to put the background `div` underneath the content `div`.

Comment: Gareth, do you mind to show me here what you mean exactly.. http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/

Answer (score 0):

I think something like:

```
<div id="background">...background stuff here...</div>
<div id="content">...content here...</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#background 
{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 1;
    ...other styles...
}
#content
{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
    overflow:scroll;
    ...other styles...
}
```

would be the place to start.

Comment: ok, the concept is clear, so the menubar is going to be defined into the div content?

Comment: Yes, I'd put everything into the content `div` except for what you want to remain static in the background. Then just treat that `div` as though it was the `body`.

Comment: - Gareth. Still struggling with this..i show you http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/4/ . Any help? I think its very simple at this stage..